# Debugging: "Java Continous Input Code" (user 2331910) and program that calculates square root sum of input

Tags: java, debugging, if-statement, while-loop

I need to create a java application that takes as input an integer larger than 3 and calculates the sum of the squares from 1 to that integer... The application should use loops.

I created boolean flags to prevent endless looping but they have not worked.

May I please receive help with debugging et cetera? I think the ordering of my while loops cause the infinite loop that this code produces.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);// instantiate scanner
    System.out.print("Enter a value greater than three :");// request input

    int i = in.nextInt(); // get input
    int sum = 3;// sum of numbers starts at three
    int j = 3;// sum of squares starts at three
    boolean loop = true;
    int sum2 = 0;
    int y = 3;//sum2 of squares starts at three


    while (loop == true && in.hasNextLine()) {// boolean flags and make sure input exists
        if (i <3 0) {
            loop = false;
        }

        while (j <= i && loop != false)// boolean flags
        {
            sum = sum + j * j;// sum the squares each time
            j++; // counter
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of the squares from one to inputed integer is: " + sum);// print sum
        System.out.println("If the number 0 is entered this application will stop!");

    }
    System.out.println("Would you like to enter another number?");

    while (in.hasNextInt() && loop != false) {// repeat process for additional input

        Scanner is = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (is.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {

            System.out.println("Please enter another number");
            int f = is.nextInt();
            while (y <= f)//
            {
                sum2 = sum2 + y * y;// sum the squares each time
                y++; // counter
            }
            System.out.println(sum2);

        } else {
            System.exit(0);// if user does not input yes, then the application quits
        }
    }
}
```

Original Question.
Do not tell me the anwser but rather guide me through the thinking.

---

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);// instantiate scanner
        System.out.print("Enter a value greater than one :");// request input

        int i = in.nextInt(); // get input
        int sum = 3;// sum of numbers starts at one
        int j = 1;// sum of squares starts at one
        boolean loop = true;
        int y = 1;
        int sum2 = 0;

        while (loop == true && in.hasNextLine()) {
            if (i == 0) {
                loop = false;
            }

            while (j <= i && loop != false)//
            {

                sum = sum + j * j;// sum the squares each time
                j++; // counter

            }
            System.out.println("The sum of the squares from one to inputed integer is: " + sum);// print sum
            System.out.println("If the number 0 is entered this application will stop!");
            loop = false;
        }

        Scanner is = new Scanner(System.in);
        CalcRoot(is, y, sum2);

    }

    private static void CalcRoot(Scanner is, int y, int sum2) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter another number?");

        while (is.hasNextLine()) {

            if (is.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {

                System.out.println("Please enter another number");
                int f = is.nextInt();
                while (y <= f)//
                {

                    sum2 = sum2 + y * y;// sum the squares each time
                    y++; // counter
                }
                System.out.println("The sum of the squares from one to inputed integer is: " + sum2);

            }

        }
    }
```

Edit II.
Again, no answers but please guide me and provide hints.

I followed @EJK's answer and was able to get 2 input and output statements. I cannot have the program ask for a third integer. May I receive help on what the problem is? @EJK does the second segment of this code denoted by the private method have a second boolean flag to indicate that the user chooses to exit?

Comment: The import and class statements were omitted for clarity.

Comment: additional code comments were added for clarity

Comment: "They have not worked" doesn't really tell us much.  What input did you provide?  What did you expect to happen, and what actually happened?

Comment: @JimLewis  Input1 = 4. Output1 = 30. Then prompt "yes" or "no". If "yes" ask for another number and calculate. Prompt "yes" or "no" again if input != no.  If "yes", ask for another number an calculate. Continue calculating unless user says something other than yes. If "no" quit application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked that the answer not be provided so...

Look at the following line:

```
while (loop == true && in.hasNextLine()) {
```

Look at the 1st condition: *loop == true*.  When the calculation is complete, make sure that you are setting that flag to false.

How's that for a non-answer answer?

Comment: @CrazyRaisans - was this helpful?

Comment: No quite, after I set the flag to false for the first loop, how can I make sure that the application will have a third loop if enough "yes" conditions are inputed? In short, if I set the first flag to false, won't that at most leave me with a maximum of two loops in the application?

Comment: Try using multiple flags.  One flag to indicate that the calculation is done, and another flag to indicate the user has chosen to continue/exit.

Comment: I edited the code as seen in my edited question. Can you help me debug Edit II? I understand your explanation and the need for boolean flags.